# How do i simultaneously groupby and mean of n rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large DataFrame with multiple `cols`, one of which has `ID` of `string`, and the others are of `float`

example of the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Child', 'Child', 'Child', 'Child', 'Baby', 'Baby', 'Baby', 'Baby'],
'income': [40000, 50000, 42000, 300, 2000, 4000, 2000, 3000],
'Height': [1.3, 1.5, 1.9, 2.0, 2.3, 1.4, 0.9, 0.8]})
```

What I want to do is a combination of calculating the average of every `n` rows of all `cols`, inside every `ID` group.
desired output:

```
steps = 3
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['Child', 'Child', 'Baby', 'Baby'],
'income': [44000, 300, 2600 , 3000],
'Height': [1.567, 2.0, 1.533, 0.8],
'Values': [3, 1, 3, 1]})
```

Where the rows are first grouped by `ID` and then the mean is taken over every 3 values in the same group. I added `Values` such that i can track how many rows are taken for that row's average of all `cols`.

I have found similar questions but I cannot seem to combine them to solve my problem:
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60850596/calculate-average-of-every-n-rows-from-a-csv-file) gives averages of `n` rows.
[This question[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55765545/issues-with-binning-using-pandas-cut) covers `pd.cut` which I might need as well, I just dont understand how the bins work.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a double groupby:

```
# set up secondary grouper
group = df.groupby('ID').cumcount().floordiv(steps)

# groupy+agg
(df.groupby(['ID', group], as_index=False, sort=False)
   .agg(**{'income': ('income', 'mean'),
           'Height': ('Height', 'mean'),
           'Values': ('Height', 'count'),
          })
)
```

output:

```
      ID        income    Height  Values
0  Child  44000.000000  1.566667       3
1  Child    300.000000  2.000000       1
2   Baby   2666.666667  1.533333       3
3   Baby   3000.000000  0.800000       1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I wanted, and applied it successfully. Instead of `'mean'` and `'count'` how would you take the `first` value of the grouped rows?